# Orbit spaces of finite groups acting on projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let     $V/G$  be the  orbit space of a finite group $G$ of automorphisms of a complex projective variety    $V$. Is     $V/G$ a projective variety?

Example:   $V/G$  is the space of sets in complex projective $n$-space $P$,  of cardinality $\le k$.  Here $V=P\times\dots\times  P$ ($k$ factors) and $G$ is the permutation group on $k$ letters.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by $V/G$? (I know its the quotient variety, but what conditions are you requiring it to satisfy?)

Comment: The natural map    $V\to V/G$    should be a morphism of projective varieties. 

Answer (score 7):

Let $A^\bullet$ be the homogeneous coordinate ring of $V$. Then $G$ acts on $A^\bullet$. Let $B^\bullet = (A^\bullet)^G$ be the ring of $G$ invariants. The projective spectrum $Proj(B^\bullet)$ is the required quotient. So, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 6):

This is true. There is a very thorough discussion of this result in Mumford's book on abelian varieties.